# Change default "open with" for Documents directory

Tags: default-programs

My `Documents` directory is automatically open with `vlc`.

How can I change this so that I can see my .doc files in Ubuntu 11.04?

Answer (score 2):

If you have trouble opening any folder and therefor can not use "RightClick (Documents) > Open With Other Application... > File Browser" you can use this from command line

`mimeopen -d ~/Downloads/`

You will get a choice of options that are related to directories. Nautilus will be #1 in this list:

```
Please choose a default application for files of type inode/directory

    1) Open Folder  (nautilus-folder-handler)
    2) Other...
```

**Make sure it says *inode/directory* and not *inode/mount*!**

After choosing 1 all folders will be opened by Nautilus.

Ofcourse this list will have more options when you have more filemanagers have installed.

Answer (score 1):

RightClick (Documents) > Open With Other Application... > File Browser

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1702576 << this may be helpful too

Answer (score -1):

Have seen this with other applications [Items On Places Menu Opens VLC](http://www.etdsonline.com/tutorials/ubuntu/415-items-on-places-menu-opens-vlc.html)