# Change default 'Open with' for document folder

Tags: default-programs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change default “open with” for Documents directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42278/change-default-open-with-for-documents-directory)

Sorry I meant my Documents Folder opens with VLC and not VCR as I said in my previous question.

Comment: You could edit your previous question, not write another one. I take the time to edit your previous question, so you can delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this for different applications. [Items On Places Menu Opens VLC](http://www.etdsonline.com/tutorials/ubuntu/415-items-on-places-menu-opens-vlc.html)

Comment: You should answer the real question, since this is likely to be closed.. http://askubuntu.com/q/42278/8515